# Ho to use If condition in LINQ Where clause

Tags: linq

Can I use if clause with Linq where?

for example: I have a table with 4 filed(Id,UserId,Type,Sing).

I want select recorde that userid is 1 and if Type="None" , Sing should True.

```
(from d in db.Receive
 where ((((d.SendType == "None") ? ((d.Signed) ? true : false) : true)) && userid==1)
 select d).ToList();
```

when i use

```
((d.SendType == "None") ? ((d.Signed) ? true : false) : true)
```

it is select records that if Type="None" , Sing should True. but when add userid  condition , don't return any records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it better:

```
from d in db.Receive
where ((d.SendType == "None" && d.Signed) || d.SendType != "None") && userid == 1)
select d
```

Answer (score 0):

and so?

```
(((d.SendType == "None") && (userid == 1)) ? ((d.Signed) ? true : false) : true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this select all recorde where !((d.SendType == "None") && (userid == 1))

Answer (score 0):

Theres lots of brackets there...if I understand you correctly userid == 1 is used regardless so why not just have

```
where (((d.SendType == "None" && userid == 1) ? ((d.Signed) ? true : false) : true)))
              select d).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this select all recorde where !((d.SendType == "None") && (userid == 1))